# Preference in androidX looks diffrent

Tags: android, android-preferences, androidx

Why `PreferenceScreen` in `AndroidX` not similar to original `PreferenceScreen`?
Even in documentation we can see in the image that the screen is shifted right.

I started new project in AndroiX and the items in `PreferenceScreen` shifted and I have no dividers.

How to give it the old look without overhead with customization?

[image]

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the preference automatically give you a space for an icon. You can disable that by disabling the space using `app:iconSpaceReserved="false"`. Something like this:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

  <PreferenceCategory
      android:title="your_title"
      app:iconSpaceReserved="false">

     ...

  </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: I am not remember this before `AndroidX`, or maybe i am wrong?

Comment: That's probably the cause. I vaguely remember, but I think I'm also facing the same problem only after upgrading to `AndroidX` preference. Facing this after upgrading my old project from support library 27 to AndroidX.

Comment: i have also strange behavior, with `androidx.preference:preference:1.0.0` `iconSpaceReserved` have no effect on `PreferenceCategory`(the title is shifted), and `androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-rc01` have effect